# I am working on a MERN app and while using express when I try to access http://localhost:5000/posts the webpage shows cannot Get/posts..here is code

Tags: mongodb, express

//code of post.js

```
import express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();

// http://localhost:5000/posts


router.get('/',(req,res) => {
    res.send('THIS WORKS!');
});


export default router;
```

//code of index.js

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';

import postRoutes from './routes/posts.js';

const app = express();



app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '30mb', extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '30mb', extended: true }))
app.use(cors());

app.use('/posts', postRoutes);

const CONNECTION_URL = 'mongodb+srv://nishushekhawat16:nickdp16@cluster0.f6wh8il.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
const PORT = process.env.PORT|| 5000;


mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Running on port:${PORT}`)))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
```

//code shows server running on port 5000 but after hitting the URL:http://localhost:5000/posts instead of displaying This works! it ends up displaying cannot Get/posts

Comment: post.js or posts.js ? And can you provide the whole error message please ?